# jQuery Tabs - Binding to the tabscreate event

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I have almost created a plugin for jQuery UI tabs that gives me next and previous buttons. However, I cannot bind to the tabscreate event to apply some logic for the first tab that is shown.

Ive noticed this inside and outside my plugin (jQuery on the page).

After doing `$('#tabs').tabs();`

This works

```
$(tabsSelector).bind("tabsshow", function (event, ui) {
  alert("On Tab Show");
});
```

This doesnt

```
$(tabsSelector).bind("tabscreate", function (event, ui) {
  alert("On Tabs Creation");
});
```

Is it purely because the tabs were created previously and if so how can I add to the create event via a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just can use method `length` to query tabs count. It is sufficient to make navigation with `select` method.

If you realy need `tabscreate` event, wrap calling `tabs()` method within your plugin, and pass you event handler there. Something like this:

```
function CustomTabs(selector){
    $( selector ).tabs({
       create: function(event, ui) { /* put your code here */ }
    });
}
```

Comment: The tab count can be queried $('#tabs').tabs('length'), so I have access to that. My tab navigation works, but only after I have clicked on any other tab (as im binding to the 'tabsshow' event). I need to bind to something that fires when the tabs are create to attach my click events. Im not sure what you mean with your second point.

Comment: Ah, yes. Regarding your edit, this is how it started out and that worked fine. The problem is that it made it hard to reuse the extra functionality across different pages (it meant adding extra code to create for all tabs where it was required) - hence I looked at a plugin. It seems strange the the [jQuery UI documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-create)  mentions being able to bind to 'tabscreate' but it doesnt work (or more likely, im not doing it right)

Comment: i think they are binding before `tabs()` is called

Comment: Yes, thats the key. Doing `$('#tabs').tabNavigator().tabs();` rather than `$('#tabs').tabs().tabNavigator();` allows access to tabscreate. tabNavigator is my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The easist way is not to use your method. Use "$(...).tabs({create: function(event,ui) {your code here} })" will work, but please keep in mind that the "create" event is called (don't know why) AFTER the "show" event (if you use it). Also keep in mind that the "ui" (specially the ui.panel) is NOT AVAILABLE.

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: What do you mean - *the UI is NOT AVAILABLE*?  Can you refer me to the appropriate jquery UI documentation on this?